# GridView Always Scroll To The Top After Success Load Next Page

Tags: android, gridview, pagination, android-recyclerview

I face a difficulty when working using `recyclerview` and `Gridview`. The problem is when my application success load next page (next data), the `recyclerview` always back to the top.

I want the `recyclerview` start from last index.

Example : First page load 10 items, after success loan next page, the recycler view start scrolling from item 8.

For resolve that problem, i have tried all the solution on stackoverflow still get nothing.

Here are my code :

```
package com.putuguna.sitehinduapk.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.putuguna.sitehinduapk.R;
import com.putuguna.sitehinduapk.activities.DetailBlogPostActivity;
import com.putuguna.sitehinduapk.models.listposts.ItemPostModel;
import com.putuguna.sitehinduapk.utils.GlobalFunction;
import com.putuguna.sitehinduapk.utils.GlobalVariable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



public abstract class ListPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListPostAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<ItemPostModel> mListPost;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListPostAdapter(List<ItemPostModel> mListPost, Context mContext) {
        this.mListPost = mListPost;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_list_post, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ItemPostModel post = mListPost.get(position);

        List<String> listURL = extractUrls(post.getContentPosting());

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(listURL.get(0))
                .into(holder.ivImagePost);

        holder.tvTitle.setText(post.getTitle());

        holder.llItemPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TO DO OnClick
            }
        });
        List<String> listLabel = post.getListLabel();
        String labelPost="";
        for(int i=0; i<listLabel.size();i++){
            labelPost += "#"+listLabel.get(i) + " ";
        }
        holder.tvLabel.setText(labelPost);

        if ((position >= getItemCount() - 1))
            load();
    }

    public abstract void load();


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListPost.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView ivImagePost;
        public TextView tvTitle;
        public LinearLayout llItemPost;
        public TextView tvLabel;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ivImagePost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image_post);
            tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_blog_title);
            llItemPost = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_item_post);
            tvLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_label_adapter);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> extractUrls(String input) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "\\b(((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~\\/|\\/)|www.)" +
                        "(\\w+:\\w+@)?(([-\\w]+\\.)+(com|org|net|gov" +
                        "|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum" +
                        "|travel|[a-z]{2}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?" +
                        "(((\\/([-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|\\/)+|\\?|#)?" +
                        "((\\?([-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" +
                        "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)" +
                        "(&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" +
                        "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*" +
                        "(#([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?\\b");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(matcher.group());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This code of  `MainActivity.java`

```
 private void getListPost(){
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION);

        BloggerApiService apiService = BloggerApiClient.getClient().create(BloggerApiService.class);
        Call<ListPostModel> call = apiService.getListPost(GlobalVariable.APP_KEY_V3);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListPostModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ListPostModel> call, Response<ListPostModel> response) {
                ListPostModel listpost = response.body();
                initDataView(listpost);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ListPostModel> call, Throwable t) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * this method used for post (next page)
     */
    private void getNextListPost(){
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION);
        BloggerApiService apiService = BloggerApiClient.getClient().create(BloggerApiService.class);
        Call<ListPostModel>  call = apiService.getNexPageListPost(GlobalVariable.APP_KEY_V3,nextPageToken);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListPostModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ListPostModel> call, Response<ListPostModel> response) {
                ListPostModel listpost = response.body();
                initDataView2(listpost);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ListPostModel> call, Throwable t) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mListPost.clear();
        getListPost();
    }

    private void initDataView(ListPostModel listpost){
        GlobalFunction.saveString(this,GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION, listpost.getNextPageToken());
        mListPost.addAll(listpost.getListItemsPost());
        mPostAdapter = new ListPostAdapter(mListPost, this) {
            @Override
            public void load() {
                ItemPostModel item = mListPost.get(mListPost.size()-1);
                getNextListPost();
            }
        };

        mRecyclerviewPost.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
        //mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mRecyclerviewPost.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mGridViewLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mGridViewLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        mRecyclerviewPost.setLayoutManager(mGridViewLayoutManager);
    }


    /**
     * this method used for set view (next page)
     * @param listpost
     */
    private void initDataView2(ListPostModel listpost){
        GlobalFunction.saveString(this,GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION, listpost.getNextPageToken());
        final String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION);
        List<ItemPostModel> itemNextPost = listpost.getListItemsPost();
//        itemNextPost.addAll(mListPost);
        mListPost.addAll(itemNextPost);
        mPostAdapter = new ListPostAdapter(mListPost, this) {
            @Override
            public void load() {
                ItemPostModel item = mListPost.get(mListPost.size()-1);
                if(nextPageToken==null){

                }else{
                    getNextListPost();
                }
            }
        };

        mRecyclerviewPost.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
        mRecyclerviewPost.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mGridViewLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mGridViewLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        mRecyclerviewPost.setLayoutManager(mGridViewLayoutManager);
an
    }
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is, your resetting the complete data again into your adapter and setting it to RecyclerView again, That's why it is re instanced everything in RecyclerView and i.e scrolling to top. Instead of that you can try something like just add /append the updated data into the list ( where you holds the data ) and then just call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method. automatically it will add the updated data and you no need to set the recycler view again.

Probably for your case you need to change your `initDataView2()` mehtod like below

```
  private void initDataView2(ListPostModel listpost){
        GlobalFunction.saveString(this,GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION, listpost.getNextPageToken());
         mListPost.addAll(listpost.getListItemsPost());\
         mPostAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

For nextPageToken thing you can move into your main code onCreate() or the  initDataView() method where you already have the adapter initialization

like this,

```
  private void initDataView(ListPostModel listpost){
        GlobalFunction.saveString(this,GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION, listpost.getNextPageToken());
        final String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.keySharedPreference.TOKEN_PAGINATION);
        mListPost.addAll(listpost.getListItemsPost());
        mPostAdapter = new ListPostAdapter(mListPost, this) {
            @Override
            public void load() {
                ItemPostModel item = mListPost.get(mListPost.size()-1);
                if(nextPageToken==null){

                }else{
                    getNextListPost();
                }
            }
        };

        mRecyclerviewPost.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
        //mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mRecyclerviewPost.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mGridViewLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mGridViewLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        mRecyclerviewPost.setLayoutManager(mGridViewLayoutManager);
    }
```

I hope it will work :)

Comment: Thanks bro, your codes makes the `recyclerview` scroll from the last item, but it gives new problem, that the `mListPost` always add the first data from the beginning. How to fix it?

Comment: It's happy to hear that. but i did n't get you. could you please elaborate r bit more specific about the new problem ? So that i can help you

Comment: for example : the first page has 1-10 items, next page has 11-20 items. After `mListPost` add the last item (11-20), the `mListPost` again add the first page 1-10 item and the next page 11-20 items. There no ends.

Comment: Ok got it. Are you sure your getting only updated data i.e ( 11-20 ) only from the getNextListPost() API > ? If yes , it won't create a problem , but actually it's not. they are giving the total 1-20 again , so that it binding that data also. Please check it once

Comment: Thank you bro @King of Masses! By a little bit modify your code works fine like what i need. Appreciated!